# change activity theme elegantly

Tags: android, android-theme

When it comes to Theme Changing activity, now my solution is: when i pressed a theme option then recreate the whole activity and `setTheme` before `super.oncreate()`.So the user will encounter screen splash when switch between themes. How to make it elegantly?

From an App called 'TickTick',it turns out to be very smooth during switch:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start recent activity without transition may seems a bit better.

```
   public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: i have switch inside navigation drawer for dark mode, when i switch on it changes to dark mode but the drawer closes. How do i stop the closing of drawer ?